# progressdialog and context - window leaked

Tags: android, android-layout

I am currently trying to define a seperate class for displaying ProgressDialogs as i dont want to create individual progressDialog instances in each and every activity. And i m currently sending the current activities context to that method. Things seems to work fine but at times (very random) it leads to a exception stating window Leaked. I even know that window leak occurs if i m trying to show dialog on a context which is finished. And i think the issue here could be because of some other part of code which is finishing my context before my dialog is shown.so i just want to make sure my method doesn't show the dialog if there is any issue with context.
 Is there any way i can know whether my passed context is currently visible on the screen or not so that i will not run into these window leaked exceptions.

And also tried replacing the context with getApplicationContext(). but the progress dialog is not shown at all with this change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: [ProgressDialog in Seperate AsyncTask](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-seperate-asynctask-class.html)

Comment: can you post the log shown when there is such problem?

Answer (score 1):

Dismiss the dialog in onPause() method .

Comment: @Override
protected Onpause()
{
   super.onPause();
  if(progressdialog!=null)
{
     progressdialog.dismiss();
}
}